# Eclipse plugin won't install from ZIP, but will install from unzipped files. "No repository found at jar:file"

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I just don't get this. I work on an Eclipse plugin that is provided as a ZIP, which is a reflection of the update-site available on a website.

Recently it was observed that the ZIP was no longer installable, though the update-site was. Unzipping the ZIP locally and installing from the result also worked.

The logged stack trace is

```
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: No repository found at jar:file:/Users/myUserName/Downloads/MyPlugins.zip!/.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.fail(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:395)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor139.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.fail(CachingRepositoryManager.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Metadata.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.doLoad(LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.runModal(LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.PreloadingRepositoryHandler$2.runModal(PreloadingRepositoryHandler.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProvisioningJob.run(ProvisioningJob.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Knowing what qualifies a 'repository', to check how this fails would be a step forward.

M.

Answer (score 0):

> Knowing what qualifies a 'repository', to check how this fails would be a step forward.

The term *repository* in this context is an [*Equinox p2 repository*](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2), often called *p2 repository*.

To be a p2 repository you typically have a `content.jar` and an `artifacts.jar` with `plugins/` and `features/` as directories.

Note that some sites provide offline installs that are intended to be simply "dropped" in and not installed. These should be unzipped into the [dropins](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/p2_dropins_format.html?cp=2_1_5_22) folder in your Eclipse install, rather than be provisioned by p2.